# Options for presenting website when website/app supports Universal Links in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios9

In iOS 9 I can register my website (FooSite) to link to my app via Universal Link. Now let's say a user in another app (BarApp) encounters an HTTP link to my app (FooApp).

- Does BarApp have the *option* to present FooSite instead of allowing iOS to resolve the universal link and launch FooApp?
- Do the options change between UIWebView, WKWebView and Safari View Controller?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. Will UIWebView just handle Universal Links automatically...because right now we have to intercept the URL and use canOpenURL on it to determine whether to call openURL ourselves... Since canOpenURL is essentially getting neutered, it would be helpful if UIWebView could determine Universal Links without help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, BarApp should not. I haven't tried to prevent this, but I can't see how, short of not firing the URI at all, BarApp could launch FooSite rather than FooApp.

To answer your second question, SFSafariViewController is extremely limited in what the developer is allowed to access. You can set an initial URL, know when the initial URL loads, and know when the user has tapped the dismiss button. That's it. No inspecting the current URL, no intervening in requests, etc.